# how to put a list of numbers from a file into an array and return the array

Tags: java, arrays, file, while-loop, scope

In this method I am trying to create an array from a file I passed into the method (the file has a list of numbers) and then I want to return the array. But when I try to run my code the error pops up that it can't find the symbol "nums".

I'm positive I have a scope problem, but I do not know how to fix this.

How do I fix this code so that it will return the array correctly?

Here is my code:

```
   //reads the numbers in the file and returns as an array
   public static int [] listNumbers(Scanner input) { 
      while (input.hasNext()) {
         int[] nums = new int[input.nextInt()];   
      }
      return nums;
   }
```

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two problems here.

Firstly, `nums` is defined inside your `while` loop, and it goes out of scope when you exit the loop. This is the cause of your compilation error. You'd need to move the definition outside of your loop if you want to return it once the loop has finished.

However, there's another problem, which is that you don't know how big your array needs to be until you've read the whole file. It would be much easier to create an `ArrayList<Integer>` and add elements to it, and then convert this to an array (if necessary) once you've read the whole file. Or just return the list, rather than an array.

```
  public static List<Integer> listNumbers(Scanner input) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
       nums.add(input.nextInt());   
    }
    return nums;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        list.add(input.nextInt());
    }

    int size = list.size();
    int[] nums = new int[size];

    int counter = 0;
    for(Integer myInt : list)
    {
        nums[counter++] = myInt;
    }    

    return nums;
```

This solution is not tested, but can give you some direction. It's also along the lines of what Simon is referring to as well.